Hive 'explain' query plan / meaning of Backup Stage
My complex query returned below 'explain' command result. This query is dealing with a huge dataset. What does backup stage mean in line number 4 (Stage-63 has a backup stage: Stage-2)?
STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-1 is a root stage
  Stage-56 depends on stages: Stage-1 , consists of Stage-63, Stage-2
  Stage-63 has a backup stage: Stage-2
  Stage-55 depends on stages: Stage-63
  Stage-54 depends on stages: Stage-2, Stage-55 , consists of Stage-62, Stage-3
  Stage-62 has a backup stage: Stage-3
  Stage-53 depends on stages: Stage-62
  Stage-61 depends on stages: Stage-3, Stage-53
  Stage-49 depends on stages: Stage-61
  Stage-48 depends on stages: Stage-49 , consists of Stage-60, Stage-8
  Stage-60 has a backup stage: Stage-8
  Stage-47 depends on stages: Stage-60
  Stage-59 depends on stages: Stage-8, Stage-47
  Stage-44 depends on stages: Stage-59
  Stage-43 depends on stages: Stage-44 , consists of Stage-58, Stage-12
  Stage-58 has a backup stage: Stage-12
  Stage-42 depends on stages: Stage-58
  Stage-57 depends on stages: Stage-12, Stage-42
  Stage-39 depends on stages: Stage-57
  Stage-12
  Stage-8
  Stage-3
  Stage-2
  Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-39

